# Rerouting all trafic from a specific port

Tags: c, networking

I'm on a Unix based OS and I'm wondering if it's possible to reroute all packets going through a specific port or coming from a specific application to another destination or discard the packets entirely.

For example I have an application T that's oblivious and sending out packets on port 44444. I have another application U which is going to "hook" onto that port and grab all the packets T is sending then reroute them somewhere else.

I want to essentially be able to do this at the usermode level, not requiring any configuration changes to the router or kernel mode. If it absolutely has to be done in the kernel then that's fair I can attempt to write a kernel mode driver for it.

One technique I know of is to simply inject a module into T and hook the send/recv functions then connect locally to U and send the packets. But this seems too hackish. Is there any API I can use to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can do this with iptables.  For example, the command

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d remote --dport 44444 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:1234
```

would intercept outgoing tcp connections to port 44444 on host `remote` and redirect them to port 1234 on the local machine.  iptables is a complex and powerful tool capable of doing many things, with lots of documentation in places like [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) and [here](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO.html)

Comment: Oh thank you that seems very useful. Do you know how Iptables might be achieving this?

Comment: does this imply that I would need to use a kernel device to hook that specific port?